# Render html in quick look to display MathJax equations

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, quicklook, html, quicklook-plugin

I am grading homework assignments for a stat class. The students knit rmd files to html. For expedience, I want to use quick view to read the files so I wouldn't have to open each of them. Unfortunately, the MathJax equations don't render and just display as text.

Is there a quick look plugin that I can use to render MathJax?

If not, could you point me to another quick preview app that doesn't require me to open each html file in a "real" browser?

Comment: When I peek via Quick Look at my Pages documents with equations created via the Blahtex supported equation editor, I can see the equations as they should as well. But that's probably because those equations are converted to something else (probably pictures) when those documents are saved. Sorry for the rambling. Could not resist speaking up when I noticed someone discussing stats, equations, macOS, and LaTeX!

Comment: That would be a useful plug in to have. +1

Comment: Just doing a cursory reading of the documentation, it renders math symbols in HTML, SVG, and MathML.  It appears to be dependent on what the author selected to render the output.